# Import Laravel user passwords to Magento passwords

Tags: php, laravel, magento, hash

I'm moving an ecommerce app from Laravel to Magento. The Laravel app uses Laravel's default password hashing, which I understand uses Bcrypt.

Magento customer imports let you import the password hash, but I think Magento uses MD5. So of course when a user attempts to log in, Magento compares an MD5 hash against a Bcrypt one.

Does anyone know a way around this? Is it possible to set Magento to use the same Bcrypt hashing as Laravel does? Or otherwise to 'convert' to Laravel hashes to something Magento can understand?

Many thanks

Comment: You certainly can't "convert" the hashes; and I'm not aware of any Magento plug-in that will allow it to work with password_hash()/password_verify()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend Customer model "Mage_Customer_Model_Customer" and write down something like this:

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Customer_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
{
    public function authenticate($login, $password)
    {
        $this->loadByEmail($login);
        if ($this->getConfirmation() && $this->isConfirmationRequired()) {
            throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed.'),
                self::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED
            );
        }
        if (!$this->validatePassword($password)) {
            $hash=$this->getPasswordHash();
            if(!$this->YourCustomFunctionForPasswordCheck($password,$hash))
            {
                throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Invalid login or password.'),
                    self::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD
                );
            }
        }

        Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_customer_authenticated', array(
           'model'    => $this,
           'password' => $password,
        ));

        return true;
    }
    public function YourCustomFunctionForPasswordCheck($password, $hash)
    {
        //Custom code for password check like Laravel.
    }
}
```